# nonhomogeneous case Ax=b of a singular matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

**Prove that the nonhomogeneous case Ax=b has no solution unless (b,y)=0, for all vectors y satisfying A* y = 0, where A* is the adjoint of A, and A is singular.**

I'm not sure how to start this. I know that A being singular means that there are either no solutions or infinitely many solutions, but I'm not sure how the inner product comes into play.

Comment: There is a link "edit" under your Question's body.  Also see the [MathJax Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to use mathematical symbols and formulas in posting.

Comment: What is y is the 0 vector? Will Ax=b have a solution?

Comment: You seem to be asking about a change(?) to your Question, but it is difficult to follow your meaning.  The original involves a condition "for all vectors $y$ satisfying $A^* y = 0$", and certainly $y=0$ is one of those.  Trivially $A^* y = 0$ when $y=0$.  Also you seem to switch the topic from characterizing when $Ax=b$ has no solution to when $Ax=b$ will have a solution.  In order to express yourself clearly, it might be better to ask a new Question rather than pose such modifications in a brief Comment.

Answer (score 1):

If $Ax=b$, then $$x^*A^*=b^*.$$

Multiplying from right by $y$ with $A^*y=0$, we have

$$x^*A^*y=b^*y=<y,b>=\overline{<b,y>}=0.$$
Hence it follows that $<b,y>=0.$